# What is a fully promoted type?

Tags: c

I came across this in va_copy(3):

> ```
> /* need a cast here since va_arg only
>  * takes fully promoted types */
> c = (char) va_arg(ap, int);
> ```

What is a fully promoted type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is referring to the rules of **integer promotion**.  Anytime an integer value with a type smaller than `int` (i.e. `char`, `short`) is used in a context where an `int` can be used, the value is promoted to an `int`.

In the case of a variadic function, the type of the arguments to a function are not known at compile time, so this promotion applies.

For example, suppose you had the following functions:

```
void f1(char c);
void f2(int count, ...);
```

They are called like this:

```
char x = 1;
f1(x);       // x is passed as char
f2(1, x);    // x is passed as int
```

This behavior is documented in section 6.3.1.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned
>   int may be used:
>
> - An object  or  expression  with  an  integer  type  (other  than int or unsigned int ) whose  integer  conversion  rank  is  less  than
>     or  equal  to  the  rank  of int and unsigned int .
> - A bit-field of type
>     _Bool , int , signed int ,or unsigned int .
>
> If  an int can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as  restricted  by  the  width,
>   for  a bit-field),  the  value  is  converted  to  an int ; otherwise,
>   it  is  converted  to  an unsigned int . These  are  called  the
>   integer promotions .  All  other  types  are  unchanged  by  the
>   integer promotions.

Comment: So, when it's not clear at compile time what can be passed, then e.g. char's are passed as int's (i.e. the values takes as much space in the stack as an int). Are there any other cases except for variadic functions?

Comment: @x-yuri It also applies to old-style function declarations (but not definitions) that have either an empty parameter list or just a list of identifiers without types.